# Opacity gradient with no border?

Tags: css, gradient

I created an opacity gradient to a div in css, but there is still the border of div visible (the black horizontal line which looks like a border-bottom)
[image]

HTML:

```
<div className="audio-caption-background">/div>
<img className="audio-img" src="audio.jpg alt=""/>
```

CSS:

```
.audio-img {
position: absolute;
}
.audio-caption-background {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index: 50;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.audio-caption-background:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, gray);
}
```

You can see the "border" at the bottom. I tried to apply 'border: none' to the divs but no luck. Is there a way to get rid of it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please add your all code.

Comment: your code is not full. if add your all codes i can help you. but now this codes is not enough. look https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/xmVamx?editors=1100

Answer (score 3):

i changed image and no bottom border is showing.. also you had a closing tag missing

```css
.audio-img {
position: absolute;
}
.audio-caption-background {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index: 50;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.audio-caption-background:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, grey);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
<div class="audio-caption-background"></div>
<img class="audio-img" height="600px" width="100%" src="https://seaduckjv.org/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/images/STEI-male-floating-TedSwem_4482-350.jpg" alt=""/>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Subial you were right the problem was not with the code I shared, it was in another class, I should update or post a new question because it seems like a bug. Thanks for your help